# Store result of SQL select in variables

Tags: sql-server

I have a simple SELECT statement in SQL server that returns multiple values as follows :

```
1 Dog
2 Cat
3 Mouse
```

I need to know if there's a way to loop through them to store each value in a variable for example :

```
declare @animal1 nvarchar(50)
declare @animal2 nvarchar(50)
declare @animal3 nvarchar(50)

@animal1 = dog
@animal2 = cat
@animal3 = mouse
```

Eventually I want all the words to form a string and to insert that string in 1 column of a 2nd table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE @animals TABLE (
id int identity(1,1),--identity is optional if your select returns an id
name varchar(50)
);

insert into @animals
--Your Select statement here

Declare @string varchar(1000);

select @string = ISNULL(@string + ', ', '') + animals.animal_name
from 
(
 Select id, name from @animals
) animals (id, animal_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @my_string varchar(1000)

select @my_string = ISNULL(@my_string + ', ', '') + animals.animal_name
from 
(
  values
    (1, 'dog'),
    (2, 'cat'),
    (3, 'mouse')
) animals (id, animal_name)

select @my_string
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you mean, but can you use a table variable?

```
DECLARE @animals TABLE (
    animal varchar(50)
    );
```

and insert the values?